# VLC not working after upgrade Ubuntu to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc

```
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
 skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
[cli] lua interface error: Error loading script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/intf/cli.luac: lua/intf/modules/host.lua:279: Interrupted.
```

Comment: try sudo apt-get upgrade vlc

Answer (score 1):

I had that same problem on Manjaro after manually installing VLC.

In my case, installing the optional dependency "qt4" did the trick.
Not sure why this dependency is "optional"...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like cli interface has got enabled in interfaces.

I don't know if you explicitly want the cli interface or not, but I can help you run the vlc and get it's GUI back so that you can configure it properly.

1. open the file "$HOME/.config/vlc/vlcrc" in any editor
   You may want to take a backup of it.
2. search for "extraintf="
3. remove everything after the equals sign ("=").
4. start the vlc.

that's it